# how to solve CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long when running main() method in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have many eclipse projects all compiling with maven clean install, then one java project java program has main method , when I try to run I am getting this issue
CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long when running main() method in eclipse neon 3, any suggestion is appreciate
I tried with changing setting.xml added this option
C:/.m2/repository
but again getting same error
somebody said add fork='true' in build.xml , but i did not find any build.xml in my java project where I am running java program
Any solution is much appreciated

I tried with changing setting.xml added this option
C:/.m2/repository
but again getting same error

Comment: Eclipse Neon is more than 7 years and 24 releases behind. If and only if the problem can be reproduced with the current version, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (the length limitation of the command line on Windows should be automatically worked around with a temporary JAR file or an `@argfile`).

Comment: Do you want Long Path Tool spam, because this is how you get Long Path Tool spam.